# QObject::connect: No such slot

Tags: c++, qt

```
#ifndef MYLABEL_H

#define MYLABEL_H
#include<QLabel>
#include<QString>
class myLabel:public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myLabel();
 public slots:
    void mySetText(int );
};

#endif // MYLABEL_H
//above is my declaration,below is my using.

  myLabel  * label = new myLabel;
 QObject::connect(slider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),label,SLOT(myText(int)));

//this is compile message:QObject::connect: No such slot myLabel::myText(int) in ../age/age.cpp:25
```

I am teaching myself C++ and Qt and have ran into an issue with the connect() function for signals and slots. I have looked all over this form and none of the solutions really work for me.

I have the Q_OBJECT macro.

I ran Clean, QMake, and Build.

Comment: You define `mySetText` and try to connect to `myText` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo, you declare `void mySetText(int );` and try to connect to  `SLOT(myText(int))` which doesn't exist. Replace with

```
Object::connect(slider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),label,SLOT(mySetText(int)));
```

Comment: Oh My God!  to my surprise,I cant find error. It maybe I loss concentration because of statying up late.thk u ,guy!. I also feel shame  to put forward this question now.